# InnoDB query duration inconsistent

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, duration

I am running a series of UPDATE commands on a nearly empty InnoDB table, and around 1 out of every 20-30 queries will inexplicably take 10 times as long as the others.  For example, the first 20 updates will take 20ms, and the 21st update will suddenly take 200ms.  I've set up an incredibly basic test:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `col1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I insert a single row into the table, and then I have a C# console program that does a series of updates:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
   long start = CurrentTimeMillis();

   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
   cmd.Connection = conn;
   cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE test SET col1=" + i + " WHERE col2=1";
   cmd.Prepare();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

   Console.WriteLine("Duration: " + (CurrentTimeMillis() - start));
}
```

This is the output I see from the program:

```
MySQL version : 5.5.17
Duration: 36
Duration: 30
Duration: 16
Duration: 26
Duration: 152
Duration: 47
Duration: 71
Duration: 77
Duration: 46
Duration: 28
Duration: 21
Duration: 25
Duration: 17
```

If I run "SHOW profile FOR QUERY #", both the "Updating" and "query end" values are abnormally high.

If I switch the table to MyISAM, the query duration is consistent, but I don't want table-locking.  Does anyone have a guess as to what is making InnoDB act this way?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of a page split causing the inconsistency?

Answer (score 0):

The updates are performed in-memory (in the buffer pool) unless `innodb_flush_method` is set to `O_DIRECT` - they are logged in the binary log (which is replayed in case of crash) and flushed to the disc once every second (by default). This means that one update in every second will be slower because of the disk I/O that happens at this time.